# Angular Prime-ng p-tree, how to change indentation?

Tags: css, angular, frontend, primeng, primeng-tree

I am using primg-ng tree for the sidebar in my project.
[image]

**The output is:**

[image]

I want to have consistent indentation without adaptively changing like the output above.
Also, I want to have the ability to change the indentation level.

*Note: I don't want virtual scrolling*

Comment: Could you elaborate...what exactly you are trying to create ? You should you Ul and LI element for side bar if possible.

Comment: I was using the primeng tree to create the sidebar as shown but I am unable to change the indentation of the sidebar.

Comment: You can use the classes `.p-tree` &  `.p-treenode-children`..

Answer (score 1):

hi your problem will be solved by using this styles

```
.p-tree .p-tree-container .p-treenode {
  padding: 0.143rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
.p-treenode-label{
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
}
```